# How to set HTTP headers win axios.interceptors?

Tags: axios

I copied the following code from [Amazon Cognito Vuex Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-vuex-module) examples to my **Vue.js** app:

```
      axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
        const response = await store.dispatch('getUserSession');
        if (response && response.accessToken && response.accessToken.jwtToken) {
          config.headers.awsToken = response.accessToken.jwtToken;
        }
        return config;
      });
```

and expected to see in the request headers something like

```
awsToken: AzWDF....
```

, but actually I am getting:

[image]

Why '**awstoken**' goes to '**Access-Control-Request-Headers**' and why it does not have a value?

I also tried

```
config.headers.common['awsToken'] = response.accessToken.jwtToken;
```

but with the same result.

It is not a problem of AWS, because **response.accessToken.jwtToken** has a valid non-empty value.

**EDIT1**: and even this example does not work in my app and gives the same result:

```
      axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer XYZ';
        return Promise.resolve(config);
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
```

**EDIT2**: I found [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993195/axios-interceptor-token-header-is-present-in-config-but-not-in-request-headers).

Comment: that looks like a CORS request going thru first.

Comment: @DanielAWhite In this case I wonder if anyone know how to switch CORS off.

Comment: you can't from the client side - your service has to be properly configured to handle it.

Comment: @DanielAWhite did you mean some configuration should be done with NPM?

Comment: no. CORS is a web browser security thing that enforces safe cross origin communication. your web server for the service will have to be configured to accept the OPTIONS cors request and respond appropriately to support the additional headers.

Comment: @DanielAWhite I have multiple web servers started in my environment. Did you mean the web server that starts when I run 'npm run dev'? As far as I see it is the web server that hosts my Vue.js app, correct? Or probably you mean the web server that handled my app API requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181556/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-alexey-starinsky).